# R function to recode values or similar (like SPSS)

Tags: r, tidyverse, recode

I have a dataframe with this structure:

```
id v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
1  .  1  .  2  3
2  1  2  3  .  .
3  3  2  .  1  .
```

And I want to recode it like this

```
id v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
1  0  3  0  2  1
2  3  2  1  0  0
3  1  2  0  3  0
```

So I want to recode values (1=3) (missing = 0) (3=1)

In SPSS this is fairly intuitive:

```
recode v1 to v5 (sysmis=0)(3=1)(1=3)(else=copy).
```

I'm looking for a similar approach in R. No preference on either base or tidyverse aproach.

Comment: `dplyr` has a function called [`recode()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/recode.html).

Answer (score 5):

Replace the `.` to `NA`, convert the type of columns (`type.convert`) to numeric, subtract from 4 and replace the `NA` with 0

```
df[df == "."] <- NA
df <- type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)
df[-1] <- 4- df[-1]
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(-id, ~ replace_na(4 - as.numeric(.x), 0)))
```

-output

```
  id v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
1  1  0  3  0  2  1
2  2  3  2  1  0  0
3  3  1  2  0  3  0
```

-output

```
> df
  id v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
1  1  0  3  0  2  1
2  2  3  2  1  0  0
3  3  1  2  0  3  0
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:3, v1 = c(".", "1", "3"), v2 = c(1L, 2L, 

2L), v3 = c(".", "3", "."), v4 = c("2", ".", "1"), v5 = c("3", 
".", ".")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 3):

This was surprisingly difficult with `recode`, but it is I think a more readable answer:

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
  mutate(across(v1:v5, ~ .x %>% 
                  replace(. == ".", 0) %>% 
                  as.numeric() %>% 
                  recode(`3` = 1, `1` = 3)
                  ))

  id v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
1  1  0  3  0  2  1
2  2  3  2  1  0  0
3  3  1  2  0  3  0
```